# I'm getting a JSON Decode error after successfully updating a resource

Tags: python, json, django, azure

I'm getting the following at after updating an index schema on the azure portal.

> JSONDecodeError at /updateIndex/

The schema is successfully updating, but I'm get this error along with 500 status code.

This is my function

```
@csrf_exempt
def updateIndex(request):
    
    url = 'https://search-test.search.windows.net/indexes/hotels-quickstar11t?api-version=2020-06-30'
    index_schema = {
        "name": "hotels-quickstar11t",  
        "fields": [
            {"name": "HotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": "true", "filterable": "true"},
            {"name": "HotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "false"},
            {"name": "Description", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "analyzer": "en.lucene"},
            {"name": "Description_fr", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "analyzer": "fr.lucene"},
            {"name": "Category", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Tags", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "ParkingIncluded", "type": "Edm.Boolean", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "LastRenovationDate", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Rating", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Address", "type": "Edm.ComplexType", 
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "StreetAddress", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "searchable": "true"},
                    {"name": "City", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "StateProvince", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "PostalCode", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "Country", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"}
                ]
            },
            {"name": "Price", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Cost", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "CostTest", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"}


        ]
    }
        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'key'}

    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=index_schema)
    index = response.json()

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue is that you're expecting a JSON formatted response back from the Search Service whereas the service actually does not return any content back by default when an index is updated. Thus the following line of code is throwing an error:

```
index = response.json()
```

If you want JSON response back, you will need to set the `Prefer` request header with `return=representation`. When you do that, you should see JSON response back.

Please change the following line of code:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'key'}
```

to

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'key', 'Prefer': 'return=representation'}
```

And you should not get this error.

You can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-index#response

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help again. You have been a life saver.

Comment: Glad to be of help .